# Eagarly loading many-to-many relationship

Tags: nhibernate, hql, nhibernate-criteria

I have a Category type and an Item type, with a bidirectional many-to-many relationship in-between.  Both sides of this relationship are lazy.  I want to write a query, either in HQL or ICriteria, that does the following: Given a category's ID, load all its items along with (eagerly loading) those items' Categories collections.  What would such a query look like?

I got as far as:

```
session.CreateQuery( "from Category c left join fetch c.Items where c.ID = :cid" )
        .SetParameter( "cid", ofCategory.ID )
        .List();
```

But I can't figure out how to fit in the part that eagerly loads each item's Categories collection.

Note that I already have it working using NHibernateUtil.Initialize().  For educational sake, however, I want to try out a different way -- possibly one that's more elegant.  So it's currently working by first calling ISession.Lock() on the related Item and category instances, then:

```
foreach ( Item i in ofCategory.Items ) {
if ( !NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(i.Categories) )
    NHibernateUtil.Initialize( i.Categories );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already explained the [difference between eager fetching and eager loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922444/why-doesnt-nhibernate-eager-fetch-my-data/6925945#6925945) in another answer on stackoverflow. As far as I know, there is no other way to load the collections then by accessing them in some way or by calling the `NHibernateUtil`.

The most elegant way is when you write the application that you don't need to load any collections and references explicitly. Lazy loading should be transparent to the business logic.